# HTTP POST Request Test using LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am new to loadrunner and my objective is to test a web server with varying number of users and varying size of fields in HTTP POST Request. My script is:

Action()
{

```
lr_start_transaction("FORM_PAGE");

web_submit_data("index.html", 
    "Action=https://<<<Server>>>/index.html", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://<<<Server>>>/form.html", 
    "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=data", "Value=<<<Content of fixed sized file, like 5KB>>>", 
    ENDITEM,
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("FORM_PAGE",LR_AUTO);

return 0;
```

}

I expected to see decreasing number of transactions and increasing number of errors when payload was increased with constant number of users. But I see that total number of transactions increase when payload is increased from, say 5KB to 15KB and further to 25KB with 100 users.

Can anyone provide inputs on this?

Updated:

Another observation is that for 15 KB, TCP connection for next iteration is initiated with SYN even before the previous one has been terminated. Hence, there is a doubt if 2 secs Http Request Timeout is actually being enforced.

In 5KB scenario, we observe that SYN for next iteration is sent after FIN of previous one is sent.

Settings: 
HTTP KeepAlive- No
HTTP Response Time-Out- 2 sec

Answer (score 0):

Define "transaction" in your context.  There are at least six possible definitions and it would be impossible to understand your question without a specific definition of transaction in your case, which could be (but not limited to)

- A Hit (single page component request and response)
- A Single web page request and response
- A Database defined logical transaction
- A Database defined read or write
- A Full completion of a business process iteration
- A reference sample based upon number of bytes into and out of a system ....
- A logical defined transaction consisting of one or more requests into the system where a response may or may not be required.

Comment: I mean a single web page request and response.

Comment: Identical file or unique files?   One user credential or many?   Think time or no think time?  Pacing interval or not?

Comment: There are no files; identical string in "value" field in each request. No credentials involved (please see the action script- that's the only thing I'm doing). No think time. No pacing interval.

Comment: No think time. No pacing interval = invalid test if modeling human behavior.   All predictability goes out the window

Comment: Attempting to simulate another system that shall send multiple HTTP POST Requests without delay